# Remote connection to dynamic public ip & private ip addresses

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Many times I connected to windows computer which has static public ip address via remote desktop over wan links. I'm wondering how could I connect to the remote computer that has dynamic public ip address & private ip addresses assigned.

I've 2 systems at home:

1. xp system-------connected to internet(dynamic public ip) & allowed other users to connected to the internet on the interface.
2. windows vista system--------enabled dhcp on the interface to access internet from xp.

How could I remotely connect from my office to the 'vista system'?. If I've a router/modem at my home it may be possible to allow the ports for the system but I don't. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a dynamic DNS client on the PC, and subscribe to a dynamic DNS service -- for example, dyndns.com will give you one dynamic hostname for free.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set up the dynamic DNS client on the XP system you will be able to access the XP system.

Now imagine you are sitting at the XP system, how would you access the Vista system from there? Once you have a solution for that, you can do it from anywhere.

A more complicated solution if you have a router. Add to your router's port forwarding rules something like:

```
port 5050  -> port x on XP
port 5051  -> port x on Vista
```

where port x is where the remote desktop software is listening. This assumes that your remote desktop client software allows you to change the destination port.

Update: Make your router give both machines the same IP address every time. See this [question](https://serverfault.com/q/110134/6543).

Comment: I don't have the router/modem, I just shared internet connection on the interface(xp- allow other to connect ...) and enabled dhcp on vista. Isn't there any way without router I can connect to vista(192.168.x.x)

Comment: Imagine you are sitting at the XP system, how would you access the Vista system from there? Once you have a solution for that, you can do it from anywhere. If you can't do it from there then just go get a router.

Answer (score 0):

[logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/)

[teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx)

ssh -R

[zebedee](http://www.winton.org.uk/zebedee/)

Comment: It's possible if I've static public ip address. How about private ip addresses?. I've no router/modem to enable the port for the systems. I just shared internet connection on the interface.